# Switch background colors between active/inactive tabs

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm migrating my site from Bootstrap to Tailwind **3** and, in the process, built-in solutions (Dropdown, Tabs, Accordion...) needed to be replaced with alternatives. The section I'm working on right now is a custom Comments Editor I created.

I'll leave a link to what Tailwind's Playground generated for me in [a CodePen](https://codepen.io/package-001/pen/gOjpjVr) because the code is longer than the maximum number of allowed characters here. The decision to create a Pen is only because in the Playground it doesn't work as the anchors open in new windows/tabs.

Anyway, the code that really matters, what makes the tabs work, is this one:

```
[data-target] {
  scroll-margin-top: 10rem;
}

[data-target]:last-of-type + [role="tabpanel"], :target + [role="tabpanel"]{
  display: flex;
}

[role="tabpanel"], :target ~ [data-target]:last-of-type + [role="tabpanel"]{
  display: none;
}
```

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to change the `background-color` of the tabs, hinting to the User which one is currently active.

To accomplish that, I would need to switch Tailwind's `bg-color-0` with `bg-color-100` and take `border-b-color-0` out of the once active tab and give it to the new one. But I don't know if I can do that only with CSS.

> Not add/remove the classes *per se*, only their corresponding styles

I've seen a lot of implementations of Pure CSS Tabs, and all of them used hidden `<input>` fields. Though this implementation doesn't use them, I've added and named them accordingly, but I could only target them with CSS if the User clicked exactly where they're positioned (top-left of the tabs) instead of any part of them.

I'm aware I'll eventually have to add JS to switch the ARIA attributes, but is the basic functionality possible to be accomplished with CSS only? If not, is there an alternative implementation with which I could?

Thank you for your time :)